# SilverStripe 3: How to sort by date, months descending BUT days ascending

Tags: sorting, templates, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have data objects **Events** being sorted by their date field, **$NewsDate** in the template as follows:

```
<% loop Events.Sort(NewsDate,DESC) %>
```

This works well and shows the most recent or future months first. However I would like the days within the month to run in an ascending order with the 1st of the month first.

Something like:

```
<% loop Events.Sort(NewsDate,DESC).Sort(NewsDate.DayOfMonth,ASC) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to do it via the template layer, you could do it with a controller method instead:

```php
# File: MyPageController.php
public function SortedEvents()
{
    return $this->data()->Events()->sort([
        'NewsDate' => 'DESC',
        'DayOfMonth' => 'ASC',
    ]);
}
```

```
# File: MyPage.ss
<% loop $SortedEvents %>
    ...
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work because I think DayOfMonth is not a field in my data object but a method of Date. https://api.silverstripe.org/3/Date.html This is the error: "Unknown column 'DayOfMonth' in 'field list'". I guess it needs to be something like 'NewsDate.DayOfMonth'. Do you know how to write this? Thanks

Comment: You won’t be able to efficiently filter by a PHP based field- perhaps you could use a DATE function in MySQL to filter instead?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found the easiest thing to do was to use InPast() and InFuture() to divide the list and have one sort ASC and the other DESC. Like this <% loop Events.Sort(NewsDate,DESC) %><% if NewsDate.InPast() %> <% loop Events.Sort(NewsDate,ASC) %><% if NewsDate.InFuture() || NewsDate.Today() %>